# wireless redirecting to router login with domain name from inside local network

Tags: routing, domain, redirect, router

I have a Smart/RG modem/router for WAN access, and a second Netgear router behind it for the wired LAN. I host a website on a computer connected (wired) to the Netgear network.

All the computers connected through ethernet to the Netgear can connect to the site by domain name as I have configured the hosts files on each of them.

However, computers connected to the wifi on either the Smart/RG or the Netgear can't connect to www.mysite.com, but they **can** connect to subdomain.mysite.com. When they go to **www**.mysite.com, they get redirected to the Smart/RG's login page. If they go to mysite.com (without the www) it works correctly. I can't figure out why this is happening.

My ISP didn't provide me a manual for the Smart/RG modem, and their [website](https://www.smartrg.com/) doesn't let you download the manual. The router configuration has no built-in help, either.

**UPDATE:**

I changed some settings in the Smart/RG port forwarding configuration. Now I can access the site by domain from outside the network by entering www.mysite.com, but if I put in mysite.com (without the www) it redirects to the router login page.

Also, the ethernet-connected devices get redirected to the login page if I leave off the www, even though both versions are in the hosts file:

```
10.x.x.x www.mysite.com
10.x.x.x mysite.com
```

[image]
[image]